# Swift fast low level String lastIndexOf

Tags: string, swift, c-strings

I need an implementation of lastIndexOf that is as fast as possible.
I am finding that the String advance function is extremely slow.
I tried using the c function strrchr, and tried copying the string to NSData and using pointers but I can't get the syntax right.
My string will always have 1 byte characters and the string i'm searching for "|" is always 1 byte also.

Any implementation using advance will be too slow but here is the fastest example I could find:

```
func indexOf(target: String, startIndex: Int) -> Int
{
    var startRange = advance(self.startIndex, startIndex)

    var range = self.rangeOfString(target, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: startRange, end: self.endIndex))

    if let range = range {
        return distance(self.startIndex, range.startIndex)
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}

func lastIndexOf(target: String) -> Int
{

    var index = -1
    var stepIndex = self.indexOf(target)
    while stepIndex > -1
    {
        index = stepIndex
        if stepIndex + target.length < self.length
        {
            stepIndex = indexOf(target, startIndex: stepIndex + target.length)
        }
        else
        {
            stepIndex = -1
        }
    }
    return index
}
```

This is an example of the string I need to parse.
    var str:String = "4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|6|0|3259744|6352141|46|14|1|0|7|7|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|8|8|3259744|6352141|4|0|22|9|0|3259744|6352141|2|3|Room1|2|72|86330534|1|0|10|9|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|11|10|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|12|11|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|13|12|3259744|6352141|4|0|4|14|0|3259744|6352141|46|24|0|5|15|0|3259744|6352141|46|654|0|66|0|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|16|0|3259744|6352141|46|4sageReceived:4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|6|0|3259744|6352141|46|14|1|0|7|7|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|8|8|3259744|6352141|4|0|22|9|0|3259744|6352141|2|3|Room1|2|72|86330534|1|0|10|9|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|11|10|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|12|11|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|13|12|3259744|6352141|4|0|4|14|0|3259744|6352141|46|24|0|5|15|0|3259744|6352141|46|654|0|66|0|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|16|0|3259744|6352141|46|4352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|6|0|3259744|6352141|46|14|1|0|7|7|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|8|8|3259744|6352141|4|0|22|9|0|3259744|6352141|2|3|Room1|2|72|86330534|1|0|10|9|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|11|10|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|12|11|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|13|12|3259744|6352141|4|0|4|14|0|3259744|6352141|46|24|0|5|15|0|3259744|6352141|46|654|0|66|0|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|16|0|3259744|6352141|46|4TCPListener.onReceived: 4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|6|0|3259744|6352141|46|14|1|0|7|7|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|8|8|3259744|6352141|4|0|22|9|0|3259744|6352141|2|3|Room1|2|72|86330534|1|0|10|9|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|11|10|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|12|11|3259744|6352141|4|1|0|13|12|3259744|6352141|4|0|4|14|0|3259744|6352141|46|24|0|5|15|0|3259744|6352141|46|654|0|66|0|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.2212834|0|4|16|0|3259744|6352141|46|4preParse
4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|Mc02|efland,nc|36.027992|-79.221283"

Comment: post your substring and indexof code! also tell us how long it's taking

Comment: Try using `NSString`, this should be faster than Swift `String`.

Comment: you're not trying to pull out the data between the '|' are you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strrchr` in Swift

```
import Darwin

let str = "4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744"

func stringLastIndexOf(src:String, target:UnicodeScalar) -> Int? {
    let c = Int32(bitPattern: target.value)
    return src.withCString { s -> Int? in
        let pos = strrchr(s, c)
        return pos != nil ? pos - s : nil
    }
}

stringLastIndexOf(str, "|") // -> {Some 28}
stringLastIndexOf(str, ",") // -> nil
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Swift 2.0 Answer

```
func lastIndexOf(s: String) -> Int? {
    if let r: Range<Index> = self.rangeOfString(s, options: .BackwardsSearch) {
        return self.startIndex.distanceTo(r.startIndex)
    }

     return Optional<Int>()
}
```

Tests

```
func testStringLastIndexOf() {
    let lastIndex = "0|2|45|7|9".lastIndexOf("|")

    XCTAssertEqual(lastIndex, 8)
}

func testStringLastIndexOfNotFound() {
    let lastIndex = "0123456789".lastIndexOf("|")

    XCTAssertEqual(lastIndex, nil);
}
```

Comment: This could be the accepted answer if the question didn't specify the character width.  Upvoted for usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Objective C files in a Swift project; in these you can use plain C code and make a function which uses `strrchr`. Then you can call this from Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in order to get all substring delimited by "|", you might test this approach:

```
import Foundation

let s = "4|0|66|5|0|3259744|6352141|1|3259744|WSMxt208L54yZ5irtHC3|..."
let a = s.componentsSeparatedByString("|")
```

The built in functions are sometimes very fast and you may be getting the required performance even by using String.

If you really need to get only the position of the last "|", you could work with utf16 representation, where advancing over the characters should be faster.

I think this should work:

```
let utf16String = s.utf16
var i = s.utf16Count - 1

while i >= 0 {
    if utf16String[i] == 124 {
        break
    }
    i--
}

println(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the characters are guaranteed as single byte, the data is huge and performance is critical then it may be worth converting to an array of bytes (UInt8) and perform the operations directly on them. You can then convert the part that you need back to a String.

Also note that Optimised builds may be much faster than Debug builds so you should do any performance testing with the optimiser on. It may also be worth checking that the optimised versions are too slow at the moment.